# How do I identify a rethrown error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a global event listener on window to log any global errors as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('error', logError);
```

But, in certain cases, I want to log business domain related errors differently. So, in my code, I wrap the risky business logic in a try.. catch, log this domain specific error and re-throw it again so that execution is stopped.

```
try {
    // some risky business logic
} catch (err) {
    // log domain specific error differently
    throw err; // re-throw error
}
```

Here, the re-thrown error is again logged in global listener. Is there a way to bypass the global listener in this case or to identify in the global listener if an error is re-thrown?

Comment: create your own [Custom Errors](https://javascript.info/custom-errors) then throw, and you always can check the `instance of` error to filter.

Comment: Create a custom error exception. You can find more on how to do it at: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to just not re-throw the error.

But if you want, you can set your own property on the error object, and then check that property in your global handler.

```
try {
    // some risky business logic
} catch (err) {
    // log domain specific error differently
    err.myNiftyAppSuppress = true;
    throw err; // re-throw error
}
```

then

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(err) {
    if (!err.myNiftyAppSuppress) {
        logError(err);
    }
});
```

Note that I used a name that's unlikely to conflict with any future standard error properties.

You could also wrap it in an object, or (in ES2015+) even your own `Error` subclass. Using an object:

```
try {
    // some risky business logic
} catch (err) {
    // log domain specific error differently
    throw {myNiftyAppError: true, err: err};
}
```

then

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(err) {
    if (!err.myNiftyAppError) {
        logError(err);
    }
});
```

Or with an `Error` subclss:

```
class MyError extends Error {
    constructor(err) {
        this.originalError = err;
    }
}
```

then

```
try {
    // some risky business logic
} catch (err) {
    // log domain specific error differently
    throw new MyError(err);
}
```

then

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(err) {
    if (!(err instanceof MyError)) {
        logError(err);
    }
});
```